# Apply function to multiple concurrent columns and output to new column - R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Ok, first of all let me generate some sample data:

```
A_X01 <- c(34, 65, 23, 43, 22)
A_X02 <- c(2, 4, 7, 8, 3)
B_X01 <- c(24, 45, 94, 23, 54)
B_X02 <- c(4, 2, 4, 9, 1)
C_X01 <- c(34, 65, 876, 45, 87)
C_X02 <- c(123, 543, 86, 87, 34)
Var <- c(3, 5, 7, 2, 3)
DF <- data.frame(A_X01, A_X02, B_X01, B_X02, C_X01, C_X02, Var)
```

What I want to do is apply an equation to the concurrent columns of A and B for both X01 and X02, with a third column "Var" used in the equation.

So far I have been doing this the following way:

```
DF$D_X01 <- (DF$A_X01 + DF$B_X01) * DF$Var 
DF$D_X02 <- (DF$A_X02 + DF$B_X02) * DF$Var
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
  A_X01 A_X02 B_X01 B_X02 C_X01 C_X02 Var D_X01 D_X02
1    34     2    24     4    34   123   3   174    18
2    65     4    45     2    65   543   5   550    30
3    23     7    94     4   876    86   7   819    77
4    43     8    23     9    45    87   2   132    34
5    22     3    54     1    87    34   3   228    12
```

As you'll appreciate this is a lot of lines of code to do something fairly simple. Meaning at present my scripts are rather long (as I have multiple columns in the actual dataset)!

One of the apply functions must be the way to go but I can't seem to get my head around it for concurrent columns. I did think about using lapply but how would I get this to work for the two lists of columns and for the right columns to be added together?

I've looked around and can't seem to find a way to do this which must be a fairly common problem?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Original question was a bit confusing so have updated with a desired output and some extra conditions.

Comment: [Tidy up your data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). You should only have two columns `A` and `B` and a factor column containing the values "X01", "X02", ...

Comment: I'd rather keep the data structure as it is. In the actual dataset I am using there are many more columns that do not have the number in the "X01" type as these columns do. Plus I am working with a database that will eventually be joined to a .shp gis dataset, where keeping the structure is important. I'll add this info to my question.

Comment: How should we know which "X01" type column should be included and which are not. Also, by `DF$A_X01 + DF$B_X01 * DF$Var` do you actually mean `(DF$A_X01 + DF$B_X01) * DF$Var`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Original question edited to make more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
indx <- gsub("\\D", "", grep("A_X|B_X", names(DF), value = TRUE)) # Retrieving indexes
indx2 <- DF[grep("A_X|B_X", names(DF))] # Considering only the columns of interest
DF[paste0("D_X", unique(indx))] <- 
   sapply(unique(indx), function(x) rowSums(indx2[which(indx == x)])*DF$Var)
DF
#   A_X01 A_X02 B_X01 B_X02 C_X01 C_X02 Var D_X01 D_X02
# 1    34     2    24     4    34   123   3   174    18
# 2    65     4    45     2    65   543   5   550    30
# 3    23     7    94     4   876    86   7   819    77
# 4    43     8    23     9    45    87   2   132    34
# 5    22     3    54     1    87    34   3   228    12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I think this would work if there weren't any other columns in the dataset with the same indexing that aren't to be included in the row sum. This is my fault for not including it in the question originally, my apologies. I've also updated my question to include a third column that is the same in both calculations.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible (including special cases) *and* provide your desired output. Currently, There is too much text in your question, while the provided example is *incorrect* and there is *no* desired output, thus it is very hard to help you. Thank you.

Comment: I agree, reading back my question was a bit muddled. I have amended and updated with a desired output and added extra conditions present in my actual dataset. My apologies!

Comment: Thanks for having the patience to answer my question David. This does work nicely for the example I provided. How about if the equation was a bit different and didn't include summing together the two indexed columns e.g. `DF$DX_01 <- DF$B_X01 / (DF$C_X01 * DF$Var)`. I'll mark the question as answered this is just a little side thought thinking about some future equations I have to implement with the data.

Comment: That would be a bit more difficult I guess. But nothing is impossible. I don't have time to think about it right now, but maybe add it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
indxA <- grep("^A", colnames(DF))
indxB <- grep("^B", colnames(DF))
f1 <- function(x,y,z) (x+y)*z
DF[sprintf('D_X%02d', indxA)] <- Map(f1 , DF[indxA], DF[indxB], list(DF$Var))
DF
#  A_X01 A_X02 B_X01 B_X02 C_X01 C_X02 Var D_X01 D_X02
#1    34     2    24     4    34   123   3   174    18
#2    65     4    45     2    65   543   5   550    30
#3    23     7    94     4   876    86   7   819    77
#4    43     8    23     9    45    87   2   132    34
#5    22     3    54     1    87    34   3   228    12
```

Or you could use `mapply`

```
DF[sprintf('D_X%02d', indxA)] <-  mapply(`+`, DF[indxA],DF[indxB])*DF$Var
```

Comment: This works really well too and can be adapted for different functions to be implemented. Thank you for taking the time to answer.